# Editing an an array of object states

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects stored in a state, the info contained in the state is dependent on the product, for example:

For example, one product may contain 2 sizes and the array would look like this:

```
const [sizes, setSizes] = useState([
{
  size: 'S',
  colors: [
   {
    color: 'red',
    stock: 10
   },
   {
    color: 'blue',
    stock: 15
   }
]
},
{
  size: 'M',
  colors: [
   {
    color: 'yellow',
    stock: 10
   },
   {
    color: 'blue',
    stock: 15
   }
]
}
])
```

But if the product contains 4, (every possible size) sizes, the state would look like:

```
const [sizes, setSizes] = useState({
{
  size: 'S',
  colors: [
   {
    color: 'red',
    stock: 10
   },
   {
    color: 'blue',
    stock: 15
   }
]
},
{
  size: 'M',
  colors: [
   {
    color: 'yellow',
    stock: 10
   },
   {
    color: 'blue',
    stock: 15
   }
]
},
{
  size: 'L',
  colors: [
   {
    color: 'yellow',
    stock: 10
   },
   {
    color: 'blue',
    stock: 15
   }
]
},
{
  size: 'XL',
  colors: [
   {
    color: 'yellow',
    stock: 10
   },
   {
    color: 'blue',
    stock: 15
   }
]
}
})
```

Now the JSX looks like:

```
  const allsizes = ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL']
    const colornames = [
     "Beige",
     "Black",
     "Blue",
     "Brown",
     "Gray",
     "Grey",
     "Green",
     'Red',
     'Purple',
     'Navy',
     'Burgundy',
     'White',
     'Yellow'
    ];
const allsizesrow = allsizes.map(size=> {
return (
  <span className={sizes?.some(x=> x.size === size)?'editsize selectededitsize':'editsize'}>
    <AccordionTab title={size}>
      <div className="colors">
        {
          colornames.map(color=> {

            return (
              <div className='sizelabel'>
                <span>{color}:</span>
                  <input 
                     onChange={(e)=> handleChange(e, size, color)}
                     value={sizes?.find(x=> x.size === size)?.colors.find(x=> x.color === color.toLowerCase())?.stock}
                     type="number" 
                  />
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    </AccordionTab>
</span>
)
})
```

And the `handleChnage` function is what I'm having issues with,
It takes 3 parameters, the new stock number (e), the color associated with the input (color) and the size associated with the input (size).

What I would like to do is update the `setSizes` state.

Here is the setup I made for the function:

```
  const handleChange = (e, size, color) => {

    const sizeExists = sizes?.some(x=> x.size === size)
    if(sizeExists) {
      const colorExists = sizes?.find(x=> x.size === size).colors.some(x=> x.color === color.toLowerCase())

      if(colorExists) {
          //update the stock of the color associated with the size
        
      }
      //color doesnt exist but size exists
      else {
        //add the object of the color associated with the new stock to the appropriate selected size object
      }

    }
    //size does not exist
    else {
      //add the selected size object along with a colors array containing the color that has a new value as an object inside the colors array of that size
    }
  
  }
```

Any idea how I can update the state in real time, which would then be used to update the new info inside my database.

Comment: Your question says `array of object` but your state holds an object of objects.

Comment: Sorry, my bad I'll fix it, its supposedd to be an array of object

Answer (score 0):

```
if(sizeExists){    
    if(colorExists) {
        let tempState=[...sizes]
        let indexOfSize =tempState.findIndex(x => x.size ==size);
        let indexOfColor=tempState[indexOfSize].findIndex(x => x.color ===color)
        tempState[indexOfSize].colors[indexOfColor].stock=e.target.value
        setSizes(tempState)
    } else {
        let tempState=[...sizes]
        let indexOfSize =tempState.findIndex(x => x.size ==size);
        tempState.colors.push({color:color,stock:e.target.value})
        setSizes(tempState)
    }
} else {    //if size does not exist
    let tempState=[...sizes]
    tempState.push({size:size,colors: [{color:color,stock,e.target.value}]})
    setSizes(tempState)
}
```

Comment: Your answer works but not when the colorExists

Answer (score 0):

Though I see the question has been answered but I would like to put this answer as here I used an utility package **immer** (award winning) which helps to update state in mutable manner and takes care of returning new state from it (it does not update the existing state). The benefit is for complex object/array data structure it's easier to update/insert/mutate the structure and having lesser lines of code promotes maintenance and readability.

You can find my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/color-size-ziesm?file=/src/ColorSizeImmer.js) here.

You can get the package [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/produce) details here

```
import produce from "immer";

....

const handleChange = (e, size, Color) => {
    const color = Color.toLowerCase();
    const exisingSize = sizes?.find((s) => s.size === size);
    if (exisingSize) {
      const existingColor = exisingSize.colors.find((c) => c.color === color);

      if (existingColor) {
        //update the stock of the color associated with the size
        const nextSize = produce(sizes, (draftSizes) => {
          draftSizes
            .find((s) => s.size === size)
            .colors.find((c) => c.color === color).stock = +e.target.value;
        });
        setSizes(nextSize);
      }
      //color doesnt exist but size exists
      else {
        //add the object of the color associated with the new stock to the appropriate selected size object
        const nextSize = produce(sizes, (draftSizes) => {
          draftSizes
            .find((s) => s.size === size)
            .colors.push({ color, stock: +e.target.value });
        });
        setSizes(nextSize);
      }
    }
    //size does not exist
    else {
      //add the selected size object along with a colors array containing the color that has a new value as an object inside the colors array of that size
      const nextSize = produce(sizes, (draftSizes) => {
        draftSizes.push({ size, colors: [{ color, stock: +e.target.value }] });
      });
      setSizes(nextSize);
    }
  };
```

**Complete code**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import produce from "immer";

const ColorSize = () => {
  const [sizes, setSizes] = useState([
    {
      size: "S",
      colors: [
        {
          color: "red",
          stock: 10
        },
        {
          color: "blue",
          stock: 15
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      size: "M",
      colors: [
        {
          color: "yellow",
          stock: 10
        },
        {
          color: "blue",
          stock: 15
        }
      ]
    }
  ]);
  const allsizes = ["S", "M", "L", "XL"];
  const colornames = [
    "Beige",
    "Black",
    "Blue",
    "Brown",
    "Gray",
    "Grey",
    "Green",
    "Red",
    "Purple",
    "Navy",
    "Burgundy",
    "White",
    "Yellow"
  ];

  const handleChange = (e, size, Color) => {
    const color = Color.toLowerCase();
    const exisingSize = sizes?.find((s) => s.size === size);
    if (exisingSize) {
      const existingColor = exisingSize.colors.find((c) => c.color === color);

      if (existingColor) {
        //update the stock of the color associated with the size
        const nextSize = produce(sizes, (draftSizes) => {
          draftSizes
            .find((s) => s.size === size)
            .colors.find((c) => c.color === color).stock = +e.target.value;
        });
        setSizes(nextSize);
      }
      //color doesnt exist but size exists
      else {
        //add the object of the color associated with the new stock to the appropriate selected size object
        const nextSize = produce(sizes, (draftSizes) => {
          draftSizes
            .find((s) => s.size === size)
            .colors.push({ color, stock: +e.target.value });
        });
        setSizes(nextSize);
      }
    }
    //size does not exist
    else {
      //add the selected size object along with a colors array containing the color that has a new value as an object inside the colors array of that size
      const nextSize = produce(sizes, (draftSizes) => {
        draftSizes.push({ size, colors: [{ color, stock: +e.target.value }] });
      });
      setSizes(nextSize);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sizes);
  }, [sizes]);

  const allsizesrow = allsizes.map((size) => {
    return (
      <span>
        <h3>{size}</h3>
        <div>
          {colornames.map((color) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <span>{color}:</span>
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, size, color)}
                  value={
                    sizes
                      ?.find((x) => x.size === size)
                      ?.colors.find((x) => x.color === color.toLowerCase())
                      ?.stock
                  }
                  type="number"
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </span>
    );
  });

  return <>{allsizesrow}</>;
};

export default ColorSize;
```